# Escaping quotes and html in a data- attribute JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

Using the HTML5 `data-` attribute, one can store JSON in HTML as shown in the HTML below. This works great with string key:value pairs but I can't figure out how to make the values include special characters or HTML.

The part of the JSON object that is giving problems is this: `Can't vote on <b>own</b> review` (also interested in more complicated HTML chunks like this: `<span style="text-decoration:underline" own</span>`. Here's a [JSFiddle for the code below.](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/aNTZ5/9/)

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var $this=$(this), data=$this.data('data');
     $('#output').html(data.message);
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type='button' data-data='{"type": "voting", "message": "Can't vote on <span style="text-decoration:underline" own</span> review"}'></button>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [escape the HTML](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php) and specifically in this example, `&` and the character used to quote the attribute value (either `"` or `'`):

```
<button type='button' data-data='{"type": "voting", "message": "Can&#39;t vote on <b>own</b> review"}'></button>
```

or:

```
<button type='button' data-data='{"type": "voting", "message": "Can&#39;t vote on <span style=&#39;text-decoration:underline&#39;>own</span> review"}'></button>
```